# Transaction happen but ethers were not send in private network

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, mining

I wanted to transfer 5 etheres from my coinbase address to my another account. 
My coinbase balance is:

```
    > eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)
     9.999999999999999999999999999999999e+33
```

So I transferred it and sendTransaction gave txhash also

```
     > personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, "jevel")
    true
 > eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, 
to:"0xe773d39957869a5edf76285fadb78e49875f273e", value:web3.toWei(5, 
"ether"), gas:21000})
INFO [09-24|10:38:50.553] Submitted transaction                    
fullhash=0x153e720efb94bfd97b3995766407407a0e95b31c92cf5665eec9338f5ce86236 
recipient=0xe773D39957869A5EDF76285fAdB78E49875F273e
"0x153e720efb94bfd97b3995766407407a0e95b31c92cf5665eec9338f5ce86236"
```

but when I checked it, it was showing null:

```
    >eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x153e720efb94bfd97b3995766407407a0e95b31c92cf5665eec9338f5ce86236")
null
```

After that I mined my transaction :

```
  INFO [09-24|11:09:13.298] Generating DAG in progress               
 epoch=0 percentage=98 elapsed=3m48.012s
INFO [09-24|11:09:15.562] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=0 
percentage=99 elapsed=3m50.277s
INFO [09-24|11:09:15.564] Generated ethash verification cache      epoch=0 
elapsed=3m50.278s
INFO [09-24|11:09:28.690] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=1 
percentage=0  elapsed=10.568s
INFO [09-24|11:09:39.675] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=1 
percentage=1  elapsed=21.553s
INFO [09-24|11:09:50.649] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=1 
percentage=2  elapsed=32.527s
INFO [09-24|11:10:01.199] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=1 
percentage=3  elapsed=43.077s
INFO [09-24|11:10:13.226] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=1 
percentage=4  elapsed=55.104s
> miner.stop()
 true
```

Then I checked the number of blocks mined:

```
    > eth.blockNumber
     0
```

It is showing 0.

My private network have zero peers. Is that the problem???

Comment: It seems to be a bug, unless you are doing something wrong. Have a read [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1473)    Alternatively, the transaction never gets mined. Please try to increase the gas limit by noticeable amount

Comment: did you mine it? what's txpool showing?

Comment: yes I mine also.@Nukil

Comment: @cryptoS. You didn't mine a block yet. Make sure the difficulty on your private testnet is not too high.

Answer (score 0):

It took time for mining to start, initially, it was generating DAG but eventually successful to transfer ether.